# Compiling A Neural Network (Python) Into An Executable

Tags: python, neural-network, executable

I have started making a project that would use ML to predict the price of an object. I was just wondering if I could make it an application and if it would work, or will it have to remain a python executable script.

Comment: what do you mean by 'make it an application'?

Comment: Are you using something like TensorFlow or sklearn? Please give full info.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your model you can do it by using pickle function seralizing is basically storing your model in disk .
just like
import pickle

```
pickle.dump(knn, open('iris.pkl', 'wb'))
```

After you done with seralizing  use restful API,s for connecting your application with model pass your input value to seralized model and output from that model can be displayed on app by returning output your model gave you.

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # get data
    data = [request.form['spatial_length'],
            request.form['spatial_width'],
            request.form['petal_length'],
            request.form['petal_width']]
    data = np.array([np.asarray(data, dtype=float)])
    # predictions
    predictions = app.model.predict(data)

    # send back to browser
    print('INFO Predictions: {}'.format(predictions))

 

    return render_template('index.html', pred= predictions)
```

this is what i have done with Iris dataset  model you can do same with your  own i don,t know yours  part of code